# Restricting Send/Recieve to a Specific IAM user and SES E-mail Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I set up an AWS SES domain and email address by verifying my domain and adding the proper DNS records then verifying the email address I want to send and receive from. I then created an IAM user that has unrestricted access to AWS SES. I then set up an S# bucket for receiving email. I have sent and received test mail from the new email address from my AWS control panel/console.

My problem is that I want to create a mail login for that email address rather than using a single IAM user that has access to all mail. I want a single new IAM user for bill@awsemail.com. Any tutorial I've seen has only explained how to set up email for sending and receiving using one all access IAM account. I've tried policy generators, but I'm never able to log into the new IAM user/account I'm trying to create from a mail application such as outlook.

I need to at least know the proper procedure if someone isn't going to go as far as writing the actual 'policy' for a new IAM user to help me with this. I'm not even sure if creating this IAM user is what's making this not work. Maybe something completely different needs to happen.

Answer (score 1):

> from a mail application such as outlook.

That isn't what SES is designed for.

Consider a few snippets from the FAQ:

> Any application with Internet access can use Amazon SES to deliver email
>
> Amazon SES is for applications that need to send arbitrary communications via email.
>
> There are two ways to process mail that you receive. You can either write an application that listens for Amazon SNS notifications from Amazon SES, retrieves the mail from Amazon S3, and processes it. Alternatively, you can write a custom AWS Lambda function.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/ses/faqs/

SES is a tool primarily targeted to *systems* that send and/or receive email, not *people*.

Having said that, SES is a tool that you could use to build (among other things) a system that is intended for people to use -- with mailboxes and individual credentials, and human-centric features... but those people would be logging in to their mailboxes on a system you built, using their cresentials on that system.

That isn't what SES is, itself.

AWS has a separate service, called WorkMail, that is human-centric, offers individual mailboxes, and [integrates with Outlook](https://aws.amazon.com/workmail/faqs/#desktop_clients).